# Model there should only be one instance of

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing this but I've been doing my 'About us' page as follows.

**models.py**

```
class AboutUs(models.Model):
    content = TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "About Us"

    def __str__(self):
        return "About Us"
```

**views.py**

```
def about_view(request):
    context = {
        "title": "About Us",
        "about": AboutUs.objects.first(),
    }
    return render(request=request,
                  template_name='main/about.html', context=context)
```

**about.html**

```
<p>{{about.content}}</p>
```

Since there should only be one about us page this makes me wonder if this is what other devs would do.

Another good example is contact info.. If I make a model like this:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    facebook = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    instagram = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    youtube = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

.. I could still have several instances of the `Contact` model which doesn't make sense.

Comment: You can create a `Page` model and then create your pages as instances of this model. It's better than creating a separate model for every page.

Comment: @xyres Not every page is a model. I just made a class to store template variables.